# OWL RDF/TTL Make an instance member of class based on property

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, turtle-rdf

I am trying to design an ontology that will categorise products based on the products components. In the example below I have a class `Ingredient` with an instance `eggs`. I want to add `apple_tart` to all classes of products that do not contain `eggs`. So in this case `apple_tart` will be added to the class `GlutenFriendly` and NOT `VeganFriendly`.

[image]

```
bakery:VeganFriendly rdf:type owl:Class ;
               rdfs:subClassOf [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                 owl:onProperty :hasIngredient ;
                                 owl:hasValue :eggs
                               ]
               owl:disjointWith bakery:Ingredient .
```

So I'm trying to create a negative association between `eggs` and the class `VeganFriendly`? The above code will add products with `eggs`...

EIDT: I'm also open to new designs that would result in the same. Preferably only using OWL/RDF/RDFS.

EDIT: Here is what I ended up with doing https://github.com/uxdxdev/bakery-ontology

Comment: `owl:complementOf` or what are you asking for?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do what you need (that I am aware of) is using [SHACL](https://github.com/TopQuadrant/shacl) rules. Assuming you have the following RDF data:

```
@prefix bakery: <http://bakery.com/ns#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .


bakery:hasIngredient rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
   rdfs:domain bakery:BakeryGood ;
   rdfs:range bakery:Ingredient .

bakery:VeganFriendly rdf:type owl:Class ;
   owl:subClassOf bakery:Ingredient . 

bakery:NonVeganFriendly rdf:type owl:Class ;
   owl:subClassOf bakery:Ingredient . 

bakery:GlutenFree rdf:type owl:Class ;
   owl:subClassOf bakery:Ingredient  . 

bakery:NonGlutenFree rdf:type owl:Class ;
   owl:subClassOf bakery:Ingredient  .      

bakery:Apple a bakery:VeganFriendly, bakery:GlutenFree .

bakery:Egg a bakery:NonVeganFriendly, bakery:GlutenFree .

bakery:Flour a bakery:VeganFriendly, bakery:NonGlutenFree .

bakery:AlmondFlour a bakery:VeganFriendly, bakery:GlutenFree .

bakery:RiceMilk a bakery:VeganFriendly, bakery:GlutenFree .


bakery:AppleTartA
  a bakery:BakedGood ;
  bakery:hasIngredient bakery:Apple, bakery:Egg, bakery:Flour .

bakery:AppleTartB
  a bakery:BakedGood ;
  bakery:hasIngredient bakery:Apple, bakery:RiceMilk, bakery:AlmondFlour .

bakery:AppleTartC
  a bakery:BakedGood ;
  bakery:hasIngredient bakery:Apple, bakery:RiceMilk, bakery:Flour .

bakery:AppleTartD
   a bakery:BakedGood ;
   bakery:hasIngredient bakery:Apple, bakery:Egg, bakery:AlmondFlour .
```

you can specify the following shape rule file:

```
@prefix bakery: <http://bakery.com/ns#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix dash: <http://datashapes.org/dash#> .
@prefix sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .


bakery:bakery:NonVeganFriendly
    a rdfs:Class, sh:NodeShape .

bakery:bakery:NonGlutenFree
    a rdfs:Class, sh:NodeShape .

bakery:BakedGood
    a rdfs:Class, sh:NodeShape ;
    sh:property [
        sh:path bakery:hasIngredient ;
        sh:class bakery:Ingredient ;
        sh:nodeKind sh:IRI ;
        sh:minCount 1 ;
    ] ;
    sh:rule [
        a sh:TripleRule ;
        sh:subject sh:this ;
        sh:predicate rdf:type ;
        sh:object bakery:VeganBakedGood ;
        sh:condition bakery:BakedGood ;
        sh:condition [
            sh:property [
                sh:path bakery:hasIngredient ;
                sh:qualifiedValueShape [ sh:class bakery:NonVeganFriendly ] ;
                sh:qualifiedMaxCount 0 ;
            ] ;
        ] ;
    ] ; 
    sh:rule [
        a sh:TripleRule ;
        sh:subject sh:this ;
        sh:predicate rdf:type ;
        sh:object bakery:NonVeganBakedGood ;
        sh:condition bakery:BakedGood ;
        sh:condition [
            sh:property [
                sh:path bakery:hasIngredient ;
                sh:qualifiedValueShape [ sh:class bakery:NonVeganFriendly ] ;
                sh:qualifiedMinCount 1 ;
            ] ;
        ] ;
    ] ; 
    sh:rule [
        a sh:TripleRule ;
        sh:subject sh:this ;
        sh:predicate rdf:type ;
        sh:object bakery:GlutenFreeBakedGood ;
        sh:condition bakery:BakedGood ;
        sh:condition [
            sh:property [
                sh:path bakery:hasIngredient ;
                sh:qualifiedValueShape [ sh:class bakery:NonGlutenFree ] ;
                sh:qualifiedMaxCount 0 ;
            ] ;
        ] ;
    ] ; 
    sh:rule [
        a sh:TripleRule ;
        sh:subject sh:this ;
        sh:predicate rdf:type ;
        sh:object bakery:NonGlutenFreeBakedGood ;
        sh:condition bakery:BakedGood ;
        sh:condition [
            sh:property [
                sh:path bakery:hasIngredient ;
                sh:qualifiedValueShape [ sh:class bakery:NonGlutenFree] ;
                sh:qualifiedMinCount 1 ;
            ] ;
        ] ;
    ] .
```

and use the following code using the Jena implementation of SHACL to execute your rules:

```
package org.shacl.tutorial;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import org.apache.jena.reasoner.Reasoner;
import org.apache.jena.reasoner.ReasonerRegistry;
import org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr;
import org.apache.jena.riot.RDFFormat;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.Marker;
import org.slf4j.MarkerFactory;
import org.topbraid.shacl.rules.RuleUtil;
import org.topbraid.spin.util.JenaUtil;

public class ShaclClassification {
  private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ShaclValidation.class);
  // Why This Failure marker
  private static final Marker WTF_MARKER = MarkerFactory.getMarker("WTF");

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {   
      Path path = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize();

      String data = "file:" + path.toFile().getAbsolutePath() + "/src/main/resources/bakery.ttl";
      String shape = "file:" + path.toFile().getAbsolutePath() + "/src/main/resources/bakeryRules.ttl";      

      Reasoner reasoner = ReasonerRegistry.getRDFSReasoner();
      Model dataModel = JenaUtil.createDefaultModel();
      dataModel.read(data);
      Model infModel = ModelFactory.createInfModel(reasoner, dataModel);
      Model shapeModel = JenaUtil.createDefaultModel();
      shapeModel.read(shape);
      Model inferenceModel = JenaUtil.createDefaultModel();

      inferenceModel = RuleUtil.executeRules(infModel, shapeModel, inferenceModel, null);

      String inferences = path.toFile().getAbsolutePath() + "/src/main/resources/inferences.ttl";
      File inferencesFile = new File(inferences);
      inferencesFile.createNewFile();     
      OutputStream reportOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(inferencesFile);

      RDFDataMgr.write(reportOutputStream, inferenceModel, RDFFormat.TTL);    
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      logger.error(WTF_MARKER, t.getMessage(), t);
    }   
  }
}
```

which will provide you with the following output:

```
<http://bakery.com/ns#AppleTartC>
        a       <http://bakery.com/ns#NonGlutenFreeBakedGood> , <http://bakery.com/ns#VeganBakedGood> .

<http://bakery.com/ns#AppleTartB>
        a       <http://bakery.com/ns#GlutenFreeBakedGood> , <http://bakery.com/ns#VeganBakedGood> .

<http://bakery.com/ns#AppleTartA>
        a       <http://bakery.com/ns#NonGlutenFreeBakedGood> , <http://bakery.com/ns#NonVeganBakedGood> .

<http://bakery.com/ns#AppleTartD>
    a       <http://bakery.com/ns#GlutenFreeBakedGood> , <http://bakery.com/ns#NonVeganBakedGood> .
```

On my blog I give a detailed explanation for this example: [Classification with SHACL rules](https://henrietteharmse.com/2018/03/15/classification-with-shacl-rules/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I'm unaware of the SHACL rules and this problem should be solvable using only OWL/RDF/RDFS.

Comment: You need closed world reasoning for this usecase, hence the reason why OWL/RDF/RDFS will not work.

Comment: On my blog I have posted this example with explanations: [Classification with SHACL rules](https://henrietteharmse.com/2018/03/15/classification-with-shacl-rules/)