# Protege: Anonymous class to subsume all classes not participate in a relation

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, swrl

Suppose there is 4 classes: `a`,`b`,`c`, `d`. 
and we have `a has_relation some b`.

I can define `c` as : `has_relation some b` to subsume `a` as its subclass.

but what if i want that the `c` to  have `d` as its subclass.

(I know `not(a has_relation some b)` is not a true answer as `d` is not explicitly defined to has or has not any relation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking this is not possible to infer due to the open world assumption. Thus, the only way to achieve this is by asserting that `A` is not related to `B`. Depending on the inferences you need, there are different ways to achieve this. In all cases you will need 2 relations: the first relation states that the relation does exist and the second relation states that the relation does not exist.

**Option 1**

If the inferences you require need to be applied to individuals, then you can specify it as follows:

```
ObjectProperty: isRelatedByRelationXOption1
    DisjointWith: 
        isNotRelatedByRelationXOption1

ObjectProperty: isNotRelatedByRelationXOption1
    DisjointWith: 
        isRelatedByRelationXOption1
```

If you then specify that individuals `x1` and `y1` are related via both these relations, the reasoner will indicate an inconsistency:

```
Individual: x1
    Facts:  
        isNotRelatedByRelationXOption1  y1,
        isRelatedByRelationXOption1  y1

Individual: y1
```

The potential disadvantage of defining the relations like this is that the following will **not** result in an inconsistency:

```
Class: A
    SubClassOf: 
        isRelatedByRelationXOption1 some B

Class: B

Class: C
      SubClassOf: 
          A,
          isNotRelatedByRelationXOption1 some B
```

If you want an inconsistency in this case, you will need to make use of Option 2.

**Option 2**

When we define the relations as below, class `C` will be unsatisfiable. Note that it is also not necessary to define the relations as `Disjoint`, except if you still want to detect individuals using both relations.

```
ObjectProperty: isRelatedByRelationXOption2
    Domain: 
        A

ObjectProperty: isNotRelatedByRelationXOption2
    Domain: 
        not (A)

 Class: A
    SubClassOf: 
         isRelatedByRelationXOption2 some B

 Class: B

 Class: C
     SubClassOf: 
         A,
         isNotRelatedByRelationXOption2 some B
```

**Option 3**

If you do not need to use Protege, you may want to consider using SHACL. See my answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49253553/owl-rdf-ttl-make-an-instance-member-of-class-based-on-property) Stackoverflow question.